# Como seria el código en C# para un menú?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, menu, switch

Como seria el codigo en C# para un menu donde tengo 3 opciones a seleccionar y en la primera opcion pide una accion de suma, en la segunda opcion muestra otro menu de 4 opciones (donde el ultimo es volver atras nuevamente)y las demas son muestran mensajes. Perdon si no soy claro.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! A que te referis con un menu? a un programa de consola? intentaste algo?

Comment: Perdon ahi la reformulo bien, no sabia eso de como preguntar muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void main()
        {
            listas l = new listas();
            int option = 0;
            do
            {
                // ╚ ╔ ╦ ╠ ═ ╬ ╣ ║ ╗ ╝ ╩ 
                Console.WriteLine("╔═══════════════════════════════════════════╗");
                Console.WriteLine("║             * MENÚ *                      ║");
                Console.WriteLine("╠═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╣");
                Console.WriteLine("║  1. Insertar        ║  2. Eliminar        ║");
                Console.WriteLine("╠═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣");
                Console.WriteLine("║  3. Buscar          ║  4. Mostrar         ║");
                Console.WriteLine("╠═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣");
                Console.WriteLine("║  5. Modificar       ║  6. Salir           ║");
                Console.WriteLine("╚═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝");
                Console.Write("Selecciona al opcion a seguir:");
                
                option=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
               
                switch (option)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Clear();
                      
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        Console.Clear();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Clear();
                       
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        Console.Clear();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.Clear();
                       
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        Console.Clear();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.Clear();
                      
                       
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        Console.Clear();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.Clear();
                      
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        Console.Clear();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        Console.Clear();
                       
                        
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        Console.Clear();
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
            } while (option!=6);
            
        }
```

Comment: a mi me parece que la respueta esta muy bien y se entiende sola!